# Ubuntu 10.10 Headless install over local network?

Tags: ubuntu

I have an old (well 2008) Acer laptop laying around that has a bad graphics card in it which means I have zero access to the screen (even when connected an external monitor thru the VGA port) and I would like to install the latest Ubuntu Server onto it. I have read a few articles about preseeding and such and have tried a couple of them, but for whatever reason neither of them worked for me so I thought I would ask all of you how I might be able to accomplish this task. By the way, the only other machine the network is a Windows XP machine if that matters at all.

Thx,
Tim

Answer (score 1):

If you have a spare, working laptop, move the disk into your working laptop for the install, then swap it back into the duff one.

Answer (score 1):

Boot off a live CD which has networking and some sort of remote terminal available. Then you connect via either a text based terminal (e.g. telnet etc) or graphical (xWindows etc), whichever is available, then run the install.